# Errors from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

I have this error occurring that states:

```
W:Ignoring file 'eduke32.list.save.1' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
W:Ignoring file 'eduke32.list.save.2' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E:Type '\' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/eduke32.list
E:The list of sources could not be read.
```

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: You have to post the contents of that file.  It seems there is a "\" somewhere and it's unacceptable since Linux is using **/** in path definitions.

Comment: Hmm I don't know how to do that.  Can you help please?  :-)

Comment: I got it.  Thanks.  I can't edit my comment anymore though.

Answer (score 1):

Open a file browser with root:

```
gksudo nautilus
```

If `gksudo` isn't installed, you can install it with `sudo apt-get install gksu` or use `sudo -H nautilus` (yes, this is fine to do).

Go to `/` (Either the name of your computer or just "Computer") and go to **etc** --> **apt** --> **sources.list.d**. Move `eduke32.list.save.1`, `eduke32.list.save.2` and `eduke32.list` to some other folder, preferably `~/` (your user directory).

Run `sudo apt-get update` again and the errors should be gone.

In the future, it would be nice if you tell us what you are doing. I can guess with reasonable certainty that this is `apt-get update` because of the errors, but it's not always possible to infer information from context.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried installing the gksudo but terminal pops up with another error and does not install.                                                            what I was orriginally doing that made the error pop us was trying to install a game but it failed and then shortly after the error popped up

Comment: this is the error that appears when trying to instal gksudo:

Comment: @TonyGiust don't bother then. Just use `sudo -H`.

Comment: So this answer worked for you?